# Mesh .dae file with textures invisible

Tags: ros, urdf, dae, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a file .dae with sketchup of a cube with Textures.

I want to put the cube over a pioneer but when I see the robot in Rviz the cube is transparent.

Should I stop using sketchup to generate the .dae and try some other program? Need some help here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203702/mesh-.dae-file-with-textures-invisible/) by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2015-02-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I MADE IT!

Only took like 1 and a half day.

To add a object with texture to your robot you should use Sketchup to make the thing you want to put in your robot.

Then you have to export it to .obj NOT .dae.

Then open the .obj file with MESHLAB and save it to .dae. You should try opening the file again with meshlab because it gives some crazy error about not having a notexture.png file. Copy random .png file and call it notexture.png.

Then add your mesh to the .urdf file and the folder with the textures. They should be .png textures.

And its done!

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) with karma: 162 on 2015-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/31854/yoo/) on 2017-10-20**:
could you please show me the example? (your dae file and urdf file)